# How to use the parent attribute in jsf components?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I noticed there is (perhaps, a new) attribute "parent" in JSF components. I believe it is meant to specify the parent for the component, so that irrespective of where the component in kept in xhtml file. its parent may be set.

But I've just failed to make a successful use of it. How do I use it to specify the parent for a component, if the know the id or clientid  of the desired JSF component ?

I get following error when I try to specify id for parent component as "parent" attribute value:

> **javax.el.ELException: Cannot coerce 'addCustomTags_Bx' of class java.lang.String to class javax.faces.component.UIComponent
>   (incompatible type)**

Comment: Could you add some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I believe it is meant to specify the parent for the component, so that irrespective of where the component in kept in xhtml file*

Nope. The `#{component.parent}` returns the component's parent component as available by [`UIComponent#getParent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getParent()) and has been in JSF since 1.0. As [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getParent()) says, the property is of type `UIComponent`, not `String`. This totally explains the EL exception you faced while trying to set it with a `String`.

There's a [`UIComponent#setParent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#setParent(javax.faces.component.UIComponent)) method as well, however you're not supposed to use it. See also the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#setParent(javax.faces.component.UIComponent)) (emphasis is *not* mine):

> `public abstract void setParent(UIComponent parent)`
>
> ...
>
> **This method must never be called by developers; a `UIComponent`'s internal implementation will call it as components are added to or removed from a parent's child `List` or facet `Map`.**

So, whatever functional requirement you had in mind, it has to be solved differently. In the future, better ask a question about [X instead of Y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Most likely you need either a `<f:facet>` (in case of custom component or composite component) or `<ui:define>` (in case of tag file or template file).

Comment: @dforce: it's not different.